# データフレームをリスト化

Tags: python, pandas

以下のコード（関数は省略はしておりますが）
以下のエラーコードがでます。
Traceback (most recent call last):
    df_L12[i] = df_clear()
NameError: name 'df_L12' is not defined
for文のあとにdfをclearしているので大丈夫かと思っていたのですがコードが通りません。
ご教授のほどよろしくおねがいします。

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wx

def df_clear():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
    return df

def ask_number():
    return 1

Remediation = int(ask_number())

for i in range(0, Remediation):
    df_L12[i] = df_clear()
    df_L14[i] = df_clear()
    df_nagate[i] = df_clear()

    if i > Remediation:

        target_dir0 = ask_dir()
        df_L12, df_L14, df_nagate = df_make(target_dir0, '.CSV',i)
        df_L12[i] = df_L12
        df_L14[i] = df_L14
        df_nagate[i] = df_nagate
```

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、このプログラムだと for 文の中の if 文で条件部分が真になることはありえません。おそらく質問者さんが意図的に削除なさった部分のプログラムと関係している if 文なのだとは思いますが、if 文の中身で `df_L12` 自体を初期化しているので、やや気になります。

Comment: df_L12[i]以前にdf_L12が初期化されていないので怒られているだけに見えますが…

Comment: ありがとうございます。初期化したらきちんと動作きました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーが起こっているのはこの行ですが、

```
df_L12[i] = df_clear()
```

この行ではおおよそ以下の 3 つのことが起こっています。

- `df_L12` の `i` 番目を探す。
- `df_clear()` を計算する。
- `df_clear()` を `df_L12` の `i` 番目に代入する。

このうち「`df_L12` の `i` 番目を探す」を行おうとすると、変数 `df_L12` がそもそも未定義なので失敗します。今回のエラーの原因はこれです。

これは何も pandas の DataFrame に限った話ではありません。たとえば Python インタプリタを起動して最初に以下のプログラムを打ち込むと、同様のエラーが起きます。

```
lst[0] = 123
```

そこでまずは Python に「`df_L12` はリストだ」ということを教えてあげないといけません。つまり、for 文を回す前に `df_L12` をリストとして初期化しておく必要があります。

質問者さんがこの for 文でどのようなことをなさりたいのかよく分からないので雰囲気で書きますが、おおよそ次のようなプログラムになるかと思います。

```
df_L12 = [None] * Remediation
for i in range(0, Remediation):
    df_L12[i] = pd.DataFrame(諸々の設定)  # 初期化
    # 更にここで何かしら計算をする
```

もっと言うと、`df_L12` のリスト構造も DataFrame の 1 つの次元として扱うほうが自然かもしれません (何をなさりたいのかによります)。